# Player not moving when transform.Translate is called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having some trouble moving my player left or right using transform.Translate.
As you can see in the code below I am calling left on the A key and right on the D.
When I run the game the Debug.Log is displaying in the console, but I am getting no movement from the player at all.

I have read the Vector3 documentation and read some forums but I am getting no luck at all. I even tried changing it to different keys like the arrows.

I have also tried **transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime);**

Maybe the way I am doing it is depreciated or there is a better way to do it?
I am using unity 2019.4.11

I am showing all of my code below, because maybe I am doing something wrong there.

Anyway, thanks for your help in advance.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    Animator anim;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        anim = this.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void StopJumping()
    {
        anim.SetBool("isJumping", false);
    }

    void StopAttacking()
    {
        anim.SetBool("isAttacking", false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            anim.SetBool("isJumping", true);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            anim.SetBool("isAttacking", true);
        }
        else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            this.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * 90);
        }
        else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            this.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * - 90);
        }
        else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            transform.Translate(new Vector3(5,0,0)); <<<<<<<---------
            Debug.Log("A key was pressed.");
        }
        else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            this.transform.Translate(1, 0, 0); <<<<<<<---------
            Debug.Log("D key was pressed.");
           
        }
    
    }
}
```

Comment: 2 things.  Are you getting rotation?  If not, Translate is not your problem. How are you assigning `transform`?  Do you need to assign it or is the script actually attached to the player?

Comment: Yes, rotation is working properly. Yeah, it will have to be unfortunatly I am making an endless runner, so I need to be able to move left and right. I've even checked the untiy key assignments in unity, it all looks good.

Comment: This is also the only script I have right now.

Comment: Is there a RigidBody on the Player? And is it constrained (Freeze Position)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The asset I was using was part of a pack. When I made my own animation and used it with the assets animations and it stopped some of the functionality from working. I just downloaded some basic motions from the asset store and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is Input.GetKey(). Right now you are detecting only when you get the key down on the frame you press it but you probably want to detect every frame the key is down like this.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    Animator anim;

    void Start()
    {
        anim = this.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void StopJumping()
    {
        anim.SetBool("isJumping", false);
    }

    void StopAttacking()
    {
        anim.SetBool("isAttacking", false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            anim.SetBool("isJumping", true);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            anim.SetBool("isAttacking", true);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            this.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * 90);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            this.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * -90);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            this.transform.Translate(5 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0); 
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            this.transform.Translate(1 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help man, that didn't work unfortunately though